# How to create Object from text file input file input in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello there I am Stuck in a problem and I can't find a way out of it ?

###### Below is the problem statement

Read the input file ‘input.txt’.

Create new object using new Object().

Inside the object create a method named as checkLeapYear().

Using this method check the given year is a leap year or not.

Read the input from ‘input.txt’.
input array with initial values.
{S1: “John”, S2:”James”, S3:”Jack” }

###### The code which is pre written is

```
var fs = require('fs');

var input = fs.readFileSync('input.txt').toString();
```

I tried it in another way

```
var fs = require('fs');
var value = fs.readFileSync("input.txt");
console.log(typeof value);
```

It returns an object
but if I try to access the values its showing nothing.

please help me with this code   [please check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXcLa.png)

Comment: because it is a string, you need to convert it to an object. JSON.parse if it is JSON. If it is not JSON you will have to find a different way to convert it.

Comment: Questions you should ask yourself: What do you expect readFileSync to return? What do the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options) say?

Answer (score 0):

The object that is returned to you is a buffer that eventually converts to string form by converting to utf8, but you have no choice but to change your input data, so:
Hi, you have two ways to do this:

1. Convert the "input.txt" file to "input.json" and save the json data in the file and after receiving it through the JSON.parse method, convert it to an object
2. Use RegExp